# Flatten an object with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Resource<TState>
{
    public TState State { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting JSON would normally be something like this

```
{
    "state": { 
        "prop1": "foo", 
        "prop2": "bar" 
    }
}
```

However I need the JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "prop1": "foo",
    "prop2": "bar"
}
```

And I need this to work with serializing and deserializing.
Is there a way to achieve this using System.Text.Json?

Comment: Why not just serialize the `State` property?

Comment: Where is your code to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I proposed the attribute https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55120
Feel free to upvote!

Comment: @phuzi Maybe op wanted to comply with some third party api and couldn't just serialize `State` property directly but still wanted to group it into `State` in the code... Rust Serde supports flattening with attributes and it can be useful thing to do... I don't understand the criticism this question received.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't serialize/deserialize the State property directly, then you could implement a generic JsonConverter that must be instatiated for every possible type you may use for TState, and add those to a JsonSerializerOptions object. Obviously only works if you know what types you will use for TState.

```
public class Resource<TState>
{
    public TState State { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceJsonConverter<TState> : JsonConverter<Resource<TState>>
{
    public override Resource<TState> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => new Resource<TState>()
        {
            State = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TState>(ref reader, options)
        };


    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Resource<TState> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize<TState>(writer, value.State, options);
}

[Fact]
public void Convert()
{
    var r = new Resource<string> { State = "test" };

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.Converters.Add(new ResourceJsonConverter<string>());

    JsonSerializer.Serialize(r, options).Should().Be("test");
}
```

Comment: *you could implement a generic JsonConverter that must be instatiated for every possible type you may use for TState* -- actually you can use the [factory converter pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter) to create a single factory that manufactures a specific converter for each `Resource<TState>` encountered on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a.State);
```

```
var state = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TState>(jsonString);
var b = new Resource<TState>
{
   State = state
};
```